# SqlPlus SP2-0734: Error

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, sqlplus

I am new to using SqlPlus but not new to using SQL, and I get the following error after writing this in my editor and attempting to run the script that I wrote. All of this appears to be valid and works on sql fiddle... I am not sure what the issue is. Any ideas?? None of the files I create seem to work....

```
SQL> start sales.sq;
```

which contains

```
1  create table salesreps
2  (empl_num number(3,0) primary key,
3  name varchar2(15) not null,
4  age number(3,0),
5  rep_office number(2,0),
6  title varchar2(10),
7  hire_date varchar2(10) not null,
8  manager number(3,0),
9  quota number(10,2),
10 sales number(10,2) not null);
```

Generating the following errors

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "name varch..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "age number..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "rep_office..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "title varc..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "hire_date ..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "manager nu..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "quota numb..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "sales numb..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
```

Comment: try _dos2unix sales.sql sales.sq_  in unix.. and executing the sql file..

Comment: Actually man, I just did some more googling on the error and it seems that sqlplus doesn't like added spaces between lines so that was the issue... Thanks for the help though

Comment: This is a useful question.  It looks like a poor question because the Oracle error messages are so misleading.  But it is precisely the sort of thing that people will run into again and again, and the answer will be helpful to them.

Comment: Yes, This is a useful questions. i too faced this issue many times in past. Sometimes, it could be really tricky for beginners.

Comment: In my case, UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark) character pair - was the culprit. Some editors (mostly on Windows), will automatically add those bytes when you save a file in UTF-8 format. Some of them give you the option not to save those bytes, which is usually the best option. 
To get rid of those bytes, try an editor like Notepad++, which gives you the option not to save those characters.
I had to copy all contents of sql file over to new file, it created file without BOM and the error disappeared.

Comment: Can one get questions reopened? This is both reproducible and extremely useful.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

By default SQL*Plus doesn't like blank lines.  However we can easily configure our SQL*Plus environment to ignore them:

```
SQL>  set sqlblanklines on
```

We can also put the setting in our glogin.sql file (assuming we're allowed to edit it, which isn't always the case).

Note that this parameter doesn't work in ancient versions of the client.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, this issue can be caused by having the UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark) encoding. It can easily be fixed by copying the contents of the file to Notepad++.

In our case, the encoding changed from UTF-8 to UTF-8 BOM while editing a sql file in Azure DevOps.

Explanation:
Some editors, will automatically add those bytes when you save a file in UTF-8 format. Some of them give you the option not to save those bytes, which is usually the best option. To get rid of those bytes, try an editor like Notepad++, which gives you the option not to save those characters.

Comment: Notepad++ solution worked for me by switching encoding type from UTF-8-BOM to UTF-8 and saving file again. Thanks