# Creating a table and getting error as ora 00907 missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a table and getting error as ora 00907 missing right parenthesis. What went wrong?

This is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE College (
    ID int, 
    NAME varchar(255), 
    Branch var char(255) NOT NULL,
    Percentage int, 
    Address varchar, 
    City varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Comment: check type of `Branch` column

Comment: You can check the answer on this [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580780/ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis) it may help you.

Comment: Var char, varchar and syntax walked into a bar. They left shortly after. Only one space left.

Comment: Two errors: (1) `var char` after `Branch` should be `varchar`. (2) you must provide a size for the `Address` (currently, `varchar` without a size).

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple errors.  Presumably, you want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Colleges (
    CollegeID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar2(255),
    Branch varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    Percentage int,
    Address varchar2(255),
    City varchar2(255)
);
```

Notes:

- Your syntax problem is the space in `var char`.
- Oracle recommends `varchar2()` over `varchar`.
- You should always include a length in the definition.
- You can inline the primary key definition.
- I prefer that the primary key include the entity name, rather than the generic `id`.
- Similarly, I prefer that the table be in the plural, because it contains multiple colleges.
- A column called `percentage` with a type of `int` is suspicious.