# Keep getting Oracle ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to create these 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Volunteer_Assigned_Care_Center
(
    VO_Person_ID    Number(10)   NOT NULL,
    Care_Center_ID  Number(5)   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CVOPersonID_PK PRIMARY KEY (CVO_Person_ID) References Volunteer (VO_Person_ID),
    CONSTRAINT CareCenterID_FK FOREIGN KEY (Care_Center_ID) References Care_Center(Care_Center_ID)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Volunteer_Supervisor
(
    PH_Person_ID    Number(10)   NOT NULL,
    EM_Person_ID    Number(10)    NOT NULL,
    VO_Person_ID    Number(10)   NOT NULL,
    End_Date    Date    NOT NULL,
    Begin_Date  Date    NOT NULL,
    Hours_Worked    Number(4)   NULL,
    PWork_Unit_ID    Number(4)   NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PHPersonID_FK FOREIGN KEY (PH_Person_ID) References Physician (PH_Person_ID),
    CONSTRAINT EMPersonID_FK FOREIGN KEY (EM_Person_ID) References Employee (EM_Person_ID),
    CONSTRAINT VOPersonID_FK FOREIGN KEY (VO_Person_ID) References Volunteer (VO_Person_ID),
    CONSTRAINT PWorkUnitID_PK PRIMARY KEY (PWork_Unit_ID) References Work_Unit (PWork_Unit_ID)
);
```

and I am getting this error:

> Error report -
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: I think this question is duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580780/ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis

Comment: A primary key doesn't 'reference' anything.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the syntax you are using to declare your `PRIMARY KEY` is `FOREIGN KEY` syntax. If you want those columns to *also* be the `PRIMARY KEY` for the table, you need to declare them as such elsewhere, for example in the column definition:

```
CREATE TABLE Volunteer_Assigned_Care_Center
(
    VO_Person_ID    Number(10)   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Care_Center_ID  Number(5)   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CVOPersonID_PK FOREIGN KEY (VO_Person_ID) References Volunteer (VO_Person_ID),
    CONSTRAINT CareCenterID_FK FOREIGN KEY (Care_Center_ID) References Care_Center(Care_Center_ID)
);
```

or with a `PRIMARY KEY` clause:

```
CREATE TABLE Volunteer_Supervisor
(
    PH_Person_ID    Number(10)   NOT NULL,
    EM_Person_ID    Number(10)    NOT NULL,
    VO_Person_ID    Number(10)   NOT NULL,
    End_Date    Date    NOT NULL,
    Begin_Date  Date    NOT NULL,
    Hours_Worked    Number(4)   NULL,
    PWork_Unit_ID    Number(4)   NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PWork_Unit_ID),
    CONSTRAINT PHPersonID_FK FOREIGN KEY (PH_Person_ID) References Physician (PH_Person_ID),
    CONSTRAINT EMPersonID_FK FOREIGN KEY (EM_Person_ID) References Employee (EM_Person_ID),
    CONSTRAINT VOPersonID_FK FOREIGN KEY (VO_Person_ID) References Volunteer (VO_Person_ID),
    CONSTRAINT PWorkUnitID_PK FOREIGN KEY (PWork_Unit_ID) References Work_Unit (PWork_Unit_ID)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, so I changed it and am STILL getting the same error:

Comment: @DominiqueConnor it is working fine on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9427bddeacf6c784d2dd40cd3b3736b4)

Comment: @DominiqueConnor you didn't  change the `PRIMARY` to `FOREIGN` in the foreign key constraint clause - Note **all** the lines starting with `CONSTRAINT` say `FOREIGN KEY`

Comment: Thank you @Nick. It fixed one of my tables. I have to change some names of the other objects to get it to work. Thanks!!