# Missing right parenthesis line 1

Tags: database, oracle, user-defined-types

I have the following code

```
create table Department2 (
  2  deptID number (15) primary key,
  3  deptName char (45),
  4  deptExt department1,
  5  DivisionID references division1); 

insert into department2 values (311, 'IT', (69193929489, 27222844821, 17897532567), 211);
```

I get the following error

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Check the following, it might provide a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24587240/5143122

Comment: Thanks i corrected it now its working

Comment: @AlexPoole - it's not necessary to include a datatype for a column which is a foreign key. See my answer.

Comment: @APC - well that's my (basic!?) lesson for today, thanks. I assume that always goes to PK in that case; and if you ref a different UK then you have to specify. But I'll do some reading. (I also hadn't realised the error was from the insert, d'oh...)

Comment: @AlexPoole - I prefer verbose declarations over minimal but I like the rigour of inheriting the datatype.

Comment: @apecPoole the thing was i forgot to add the array datatype that i created lmfao

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution based on a couple of assumptions:

- `department1` is a SQL nested table type
- `division1` is a table with a primary key

So we can create the table like this:

```
create table Department2 (
deptID number (15) primary key,
deptName char (45),
deptExt department1,
 DivisionID references division1)
       NESTED TABLE deptExt STORE AS deptExt_tab
 ;
```

Note that it not necessary to further define `DivisionID`: it inherits its datatype from the primary key column of the referenced table. The NESTED TABLE clause is required to create a nested table column, and its absence from the question is troubling.

Having created the table like this the posted insert statement does indeed hurl `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`. This is due to the collection of department IDs: we are instantiating a type and that means we need to reference the collection in the VALUES clause:

```
insert into department2 
values (311, 'IT', department1(69193929489, 27222844821, 17897532567), 211);
```

I have posted [a working demo on db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=275d5e6ee175a8bced311f62405d8405)