# How to Run a Select statement from SPARK for an oracle table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run below statement in spark to unload data from oracle using select statement...

```
val query_result = spark.read.format("jdbc")
           .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@****:****:****")
           .option("user", "user1").option("password", "****")
           .option("query", "SELECT * FROM TABLE")
           .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
           .option("inferSchema", "true")
           .load()
```

But i was getting below error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: look like your query is invalid

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580780/ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis