# can't set a foreign key on oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Here is my code:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE manufacturer(
  manufacturer_id integer primary key,
  manufacturer_name varchar2(20)
);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE models(
  model_id integer primary key,
  model_name varchar2(20),
  model_year integer,
  eng_cylinder integer,
  eng_horsepower integer,
  manufacturer_id int foreign key references manufacturer(manufacturer_id)
);
```

and it gave me this error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

What is wrong with parenthesis in my code? this only happens when i set foreign key.

Note: i am using SQL cmd from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition.

I've tried making theses tables on MySQL and it worked fine.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580780/ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis It says that this problem is often a generic syntax error, not actually mismatched parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No "FOREIGN KEY" keyword is used for inline constraints.  So, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE manufacturer (manufacturer_id integer primary key, manufacturer_name varchar2(20));

CREATE TABLE models (model_id integer primary key, 
                     model_name varchar2(20),
                     model_year integer, 
                     eng_cylinder integer, 
                     eng_horsepower integer,
                     manufacturer_id int constraint models_fk1 references manufacturer(manufacturer_id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Right, just as Matthew already said.

---

Alternatively, create the foreign key constraint *out of line* - then you do use the `foreign key` part of the syntax (see line #9):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE models
  2    (model_id integer primary key,
  3     model_name varchar2(20),
  4     model_year integer,
  5     eng_cylinder integer,
  6     eng_horsepower integer,
  7     manufacturer_id int,
  8     --
  9     constraint models_fk1 foreign key (manufacturer_id) references manufacturer(manufacturer_id)
 10    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

Or, yet another option - `alter table`:

```
SQL> alter table models add constraint models_fk1 foreign key
  2    (manufacturer_id) references manufacturer (manufacturer_id);

Table altered.
```

Comment: This is actually the way I prefer - all constraints (except NOT NULL) out of line.  I answered with the inline constraint because that seemed to be the way the OP was going.  But this is a good addition I should have mentioned in my answer.